# Get connected user information

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

in a spring boot application, i use spring security and rest.

My setup of my security.

```
public class GymApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        http.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
        http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
        http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
}
```

When user do a requesty, in the controller, i would like to have it's id

I see on old tutorial

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

is it still ok with spring boot?
so i need to this in each methof of my controller

Comment: Why would it have changed? The means of configuration has changed not the usage of the API. So yes you need to do that (or simply add a method argument of type `Principal` or use the `@AuthenticatedPrincipal` as explained in the reference guide which I suggest you to read).

Comment: It's `@AuthenticationPrincipal`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal